# Can the vagrant hostsupdater plugin add a hosts entry for a public network?

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant version: 1.6.3
Vagrant plugins installed:
  vagrant-hostsupdater (0.0.11)
  vagrant-login (1.0.1, system)
  vagrant-share (1.1.0, system)
  vagrant-vbguest (0.10.0)
  vagrant-vbox-snapshot (0.0.5)

My vagrant file defines a private and public network - The hosts updater plugin adds an /etc/hosts entry for the private network but not the public network - any solution to this?
(other than manually entering it - i know its a static IP but i am lazy) - thanks

my Vagrantfile follows (which I am proud of, works perfectly) ...

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

IP_END = 88
HTTP_PORT = 8888
BOX_NAME = "hashicorp/precise32"
HOST_NAME = "precise32.com"
GUI = false

# vagrantup.com
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = BOX_NAME
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.#{IP_END}"
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "wlan0", ip: "192.168.1.#{IP_END}"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: HTTP_PORT
  config.vm.hostname = HOST_NAME

  # 'vagrant box outdated' forces a check update
  config.vm.box_check_update = true

  config.ssh.forward_agent = false

  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = GUI
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--clipboard", "bidirectional"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--draganddrop", "bidirectional"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like someone already submitted a pull request to the hostsupdater plugin: https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater/pull/47

I don't know how actively maintained this plugin is (last commit was October 2013). At a minimum you could implement the same code change from that pull request in your local copy of the plugin.

Comment: Just a quick update.  I gained maintainer access on the repo and will be making updates and accepting pull requests!

Comment: CGSmith105 could you please confirm whether this plugin now adds entries for public networks?

Comment: @danday74 yes public networks works.  Feel free to reach out on GitHub